# In C Char from Pointer char get Number

Tags: c, pointers, char, malloc

I want to assign char from pointer char at specified index, but malloc set to pointer a lot of number:

```
char *pointer = (char*)malloc(3);
char *chars = "hello";

pointer[1]= chars[1];

char only = pointer[1];

if(only=='e')//here return false, why??
{
 printf("ok");
}
```

when I try to set **only** as pointer[1], **only** value became \376 or another number.
What's wrong?

**EDIT**

So, is there a way to get the value ('e') from *char pointer[i]* and not get the ascii or another number like \376 ?

Comment: Try adding a newline to your `printf` - to flush the output: `printf("ok\n");`.

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>` and get rid of the cast to the return value of `malloc()`

Comment: How did you obtain the value `\376` (octal for `254`)?

Comment: The complete value of the char pointer is: **0xdf4cb0 "\360\027\337\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\253\376\356\376\356\376\356\376\356\376\356\376", <incomplete sequence \356\376>**

Comment: @VLN  `pointer` is optimized out and your debugger is showing garbage.  Change `if(only=='e') {  printf("ok"); }`  to `printf("%d %d\n", only, only=='e');` for insight.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I tried to replace with `printf("%d %d\n", only, only=='e');` and it shows **1 0**   So the condition return false, why?

Comment: @VLN, Good first step - the condition should be false when `only` is `1`..  Try `printf("%d %d\n", pointer[1], chars[1]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to be 'that' person, but this code works fine on my machine. What compiler are you using - and with what options? I tried using both GCC and Clang and they both printed "ok".

You could try changing `printf("ok");` to `printf("ok\n");`. It may be that your terminal is not printing "ok" because there is no newline to 'flush the buffer'. I think that this is a common problem on Windows.

The code that you show doesn't seem to be the entire program - the main() function is missing. If you could add the rest of your program to your post, we could probably help find the problem more easily.

EDIT: Try changing malloc(3) to calloc(3,1). This will initialise the memory to zeroes instead of garbage values. If 'only' then becomes zero, we know that the problem is with the pointer assignment and not the memory allocation.